How can I calculate the medial axis of an ellipse?
I'm trying to understand more about the medial axis and its connection to the reach concept. Suppose I have an ellipse given by $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, and I want to find the coordinates of the medial axis. Is there a closed formula for this? What about for higher-dimensional ellipsoids? According to From wikipedia, I assume the medial axis lies along the major axis of the ellipse.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Please refer to evolute of ellipse and centro-surface of ellipsoid.

All you need to know is that the radius of curvature at the endpoints of the major axis of an ellipse is $b^2/a$.
